# How to change/create the rldc, reportViewer Object and the dataSet at runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I'm using ReportViewer to create some reports to my web application and I want to know:

It is possible to use ReportViewer without pre-creating the .rdlc file...the dataSet...and all the stuff?

I want to make instances of these objects, set theirs properties at runtime, to not include too much files into my application (30 reports x 3 files [dataSet, .rdlc and .aspx])

The following method explain a bit of my toughts:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
    //getting the string connection
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;
    //estabilishing connection
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        string sql = @"EXEC SP_PRODUCTS"; // or another SQL command

        //opening connection
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dte = new DataTable();

        //filling the dataTable with the command above
        adp.Fill(dte);

        //closing connection
        conn.Close();

        //defining which report the component will render
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "myReport.rdlc";

        //adding the dataSource Adicionando o data source, it's important passing the same name you defined before
        //at this moment, i didn't understood if the DataSource is being created populated by the dte datatable or
        //if it is just binding the dte datatable to an existing dataSource named "Products
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource("Products", dte));

        //without this it wont work
        ReportViewer1.DataBind();
    }
```

}

Any idea of how to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a rdlc file, but what you can do is to fill this rdlc with columns you need and depending on what you need you show/hide the columns. You can use parameters for this. In this way you can use only one rdlc file. You also can define an object (and make only one dataset) for all your columns you need and you populate it depending on report.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly I've already solved this but not the way I wished.
I've created a .rdlc file for each report(sad), one dataset(as I wished) with all the needed tableadapters and one webform(as I wished).
I think this way it will consume less processing time and make the code easier to understand. Thank you anyway!
I'll mark this as correct because if I knew these information 4 days ago it would have helped me.